# Getting incorrect time

Tags: javascript, momentjs, server-side

I'm trying to get a time related to my location. According to my country time at my place is GMT+5. But when I use the following code in my firebase cloud function, it always gives me GMT+0 time.

```
const time = new Date();
const currentTime = time.toLocaleString('en-US', { 
  hour: 'numeric', 
  minute: 'numeric', 
  hour12: true 
})
```

If I use the above code in the console of any website, it is giving me the correct time. i.e. GMT+5. Anyone know how can I get the correct time according to my region?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.

If your firebase cloud function is running in the cloud, it is probably not running on a computer that is in the same timezone as you, thus the timezone difference.

If you want your firebase cloud function to get the timezone the user sending the request, you have to pass the timezone or the date as part of your request, instead of computing it inside your cloud function.